# What does struct { .attr = value } syntax mean?

Tags: c, fuse

From `fuse/examples/fsel.c`

```
static struct fuse_operations fsel_oper = {
    .getattr    = fsel_getattr,
    .readdir    = fsel_readdir,
    .open       = fsel_open,
    .release    = fsel_release,
    .read       = fsel_read,
    .poll       = fsel_poll,
};
```

this is the definitionof `fuse_operations`

```
struct fuse_operations_compat25 {
    int (*getattr) (const char *, struct stat *);
    int (*readlink) (const char *, char *, size_t);
    int (*getdir) (const char *, fuse_dirh_t, fuse_dirfil_t);
    int (*mknod) (const char *, mode_t, dev_t);
    int (*mkdir) (const char *, mode_t);
    int (*unlink) (const char *);
    int (*rmdir) (const char *);
    .....
};
```

so what do those `.` mean? It's the first time I see that

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Comment: Initialization that it specify a member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the field that is named after the `.` will have that value.

For example, the `gettr` function pointer will point to the `fsel_getattr` function.

Comment: and what happens with non-initialized values? are they set to 0?